# Which silver chests should I prioritise opening?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

As [Magic Keys](https://exviuswiki.com/Magic_Key) are quite hard to come by, I'd like to know which [Silver Chest](https://exviuswiki.com/Silver_Chests) rewards I should be prioritising, so that I'm not wasting my Magic Keys.

[The ExviusWiki has a list of the Silver Chests](https://exviuswiki.com/Silver_Chests), but no guidance on which items are the most beneficial.

So which chests should I open first?

Comment: Such a suggestion list would be pointless because it depends on what your party is, what you already have and what you need.

Comment: As it's a specific list of items, there are items which would hold more value to players than others. Items such as `Green Beret` would no doubt be at the bottom as it's purchasable. Thing such as `Barwatera` would be higher as I'm not aware of another way to obtain the recipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Silver Chests](https://exviuswiki.com/Silver_Chests) primarily contain recipes for abilities, equipment, and skills. Some of these you can purchase/create by other means, which minimizes the need to use a silver key for the respective chest.

With that being said, there are a few items that are very helpful, due to use and/or rarity (as of current release, 9/9/16).

1. **Barblizzara**: Unless you have [Cerius](https://exviuswiki.com/Cerius) (who has the superior Barblizzaga) or [Mizell](https://exviuswiki.com/Mizell), this is the best way to get resistance to ice damage, needed for a few of the currently toughest fights ([Demon Chimera](https://exviuswiki.com/Demon_Chimera), Colosseum [Frost Dragon](https://exviuswiki.com/Frost_Dragon)).
2. **Barwatera/Barstonra/Baraerora**: There's no other way to protect the entire party against water, earth, or wind resistance, respectively. Not as essential as Barblizzara, however, as these elements aren't used as often, especially in current high-level fights.
3. **Stat Enhancers**: Unless you grind out some tough trust master rewards, this is the easiest way to get equippable abilities to enhance your stats. MAG +10% for mages, SPR +10% for healers, etc.

There are some others that may be handy, but it entirely depends on your party and what units/skills you have available. [Mental Break](https://exviuswiki.com/Mental_Break) is ok, but [does not stack with other debuffs](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFBraveExvius/comments/3w6ir3/deshellmental_break_and_deprotectarmor_break/), making it outclassed by a user (or user equipped with an esper) having [Deshell](https://exviuswiki.com/Deshell), or even better, [Full Break](https://exviuswiki.com/Full_Break). Similarly, [Bravery](https://exviuswiki.com/Bravery) is ok, but far outclassed by a unit with [Cheer](https://exviuswiki.com/Cheer).

Comment: Attack +10% is probably the best thing on the list, found at the water shrine. Cloud of Darkness now has Omni-Veil, which is bar-ra everything.